# Declaring methods in different way

Tags: javascript, methods

I have a question about declaring methods for a function in JavaScript. Suppose that I declare a function Monster in these two following ways:
First way:

```
function Monster() {
  this.growl = () => {
    console.log('grrr!');
  }
}
```

Second Way:

```
function Monster() {
}
Monster.prototype.growl = () => {
  console.log('grrr!');
}
```

The question is: when I instantiate n monster I do create n methods for both way of declaration or I create only one method for all the monsters I instantiated?

Comment: n methods in the first case, only one in the second case.

Comment: Both `this.growl() = ...` and `Monster.prototype.growl() = ...` are syntax errors

Comment: @HaoWu you're right I corrected it

Comment: @VLAZ can you kindly explain me why?

Comment: First case it's adding a method on each instance. Second case adds one method to the prototype that all instances share.

Comment: Don't use arrow functions for methods, they cannot access the instance using `this`